# Object not persisted after validation with no errors

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm migrating to Grails 3.1.15 (Hibernate 4) from Grails 2.4.5 (Hibernate 3) and noticed that some of my controller actions don't work any more.

I have the following action (simplified)

```
def create() {
        def myDomainObject = myDomainservice.getDefault()
        if (myDomainObject.validate()) {
            myDomainObject.save()
            render 'OK'
        } else {
            render 'WRONG'
        }
}
```

This action worked fine in Grails 2. An object was created when the validation returned no errors.

In Grails 3 however this is not true any more. The action call executes without errors but the object is not stored in the db (id is assigned however).

After some troubleshooting I've came to a conclusion that calling `validate()` ignores somehow the `save()` ( validate() doesn't detect any problems).

Adding `@Transactional` or explicitly flushing `save(flush:true)` fixes the problem.

Am I able to get the old behaviour back?

I've checked the `hibernate.flush.mode = AUTO` and it's the same in both versions.

Comment: cos your controller actions are not transactional. try moving it a service or adding MyObject.withTransaction { //do something}. I must say it seems all rather backwards since you are calling a service to get stuff then saving in a controller haha comical

Answer (score 0):

Core application logic (as domains saving) in controllers is discouraged by Grails team at least due to unclean [separation of conserns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Try to move your logic to service (they are transactional by default, i.e. are annotated with @Transactional) and you cover 2 goals at once:

1. Cleaner code
2. Working functionality